# Microsoft.Datasync.Client.SQLiteStore.SQLiteException: Unable to configure sqlite3 for URI connection strings

Tags: xamarin.android, azure-mobile-services

I am getting this error "Microsoft.Datasync.Client.SQLiteStore.SQLiteException: Unable to configure sqlite3 for URI connection strings." when trying to create an offline store in xamarin android project using the  Microsoft.DataSync.Client.SQLiteStore. The target android version is Android 12.

This is how i am creating an offline store.

`var dbPath = $"{FileSystem.AppDataDirectory}/devstore.db"; var lcStore = new OfflineSQLiteStore($"file:/{dbPath}?mode=rwc");`

Any idea why this is happening?.

I tried searching for some resolution and changed the android folder paths to personal and all as per some advice but no luck resolving this.

Answer (score 0):

Likely, SQLite is already configured. Underneath, sqlite3_config() returns SQLITE_MISUSE, indicating that SQLite has already been configured.

There is a pending release that will fix that specific problem, and I'll be producing a new NuGet package later on today (Feb 3rd) to correct this problem.